# presentModalViewController: leftBarButtonItem blue while view is loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

When I open a view with presentModalViewController, a back button that I created while the transition is playing after it finishes play ( aka. view is presented), then it turns to the color I expect, is based on tint color that I set to navigationBar.

How can I get rid of that blue button, making it to look how it is once the animation stops playing?

I added the button on the viewDidLoad and also with IB. Same result. The tint color I set using a category as follows:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBar_Custom)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.019 saturation:0.990 brightness:0.4850 alpha:1.000];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're setting the tint color in viewDidAppear: - try setting the it in viewWillAppear:, and always calls the superclass's implementation!

Also, you should rather add a cancel/done button to a modal view controller.

Comment: You shouldn't override drawRect: in a category. There's no way to call the navbar's original drawRect: implementation. You should rather set the tintColor in init, viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear:

Answer (score 0):

`-drawRect:` is where you'd put code that does any custom drawing, but it really isn't the place for setting the tint. (Also, it's not nice to override methods in a category.)

Instead, set the tint color when you add the button in `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: thank you for your advices. Doing that didn't help. Same result.